# How to modify MPI blocking send and receive to non-blocking

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, message-passing

I am trying to understand the difference between blocking and non-blocking message passing mechanisms in parallel processing using MPI. Suppose we have the following blocking code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include "mpi.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int maximum_message_length = 100;
    const int rank_0= 0;
    char message[maximum_message_length+1]; 
    MPI_Status status; /* Info about receive status */ 
    int my_rank; /* This process ID */
    int num_procs; /* Number of processes in run */ 
    int source; /* Process ID to receive from */
    int destination; /* Process ID to send to */
    int tag = 0; /* Message ID */

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank); 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);

    /* clients processes */
    if (my_rank != server_rank) {
        sprintf(message, "Hello world from process# %d", my_rank);
        MPI_Send(message, strlen(message) + 1, MPI_CHAR, rank_0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    } else {    
    /* rank 0 process */ 
        for (source = 0; source < num_procs; source++) { 
            if (source != rank_0) {
                MPI_Recv(message, maximum_message_length + 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, 
                MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
         MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Each processor executes its task and send it back to rank_0 (the receiver). rank_0 will run a loop from 1 to n-1 processes and print them sequentially (i step in the loop may not proceed if the current client hasn't sent its task yet). How do I modify this code to achieve the non-blocking mechanism using `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Irecv`? Do I need to remove the loop in receiver part (rank_0) and explicitly state MPI_Irecv(..) for each client, i.e.

```
MPI_Irecv(message, maximum_message_length + 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, 
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you still want to have some order on the receiving process when printing the messages?

Comment: @haraldkl there isn't any guarantee in OP's code written as-is that the messages will be received in any order anyway, so I assume no.

Comment: No, order doesn't matter

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Yes there is an imposed order in OPs code, as the blocking recvs have to be performed in the order of the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you do with non-blocking communication is to post the communication and then immediately proceed with your program to do other stuff, which again might be posting more communication. Especially, you can post all receives at once, and wait on them to complete only later on.
This is what you typically would do in your scenario here.

Note however, that this specific setup is a bad example, as it basically just reimplements an [MPI_Gather](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node70.html)!

Here is how you typically would go about the non-blocking communication in your setup. First, you need some storage for all the messages to end up in, and also a list of request handles to keep track of the non-blocking communication requests, thus your first part of the code needs to be changed accordingly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int maximum_message_length = 100;
    const int server_rank = 0;
    char message[maximum_message_length+1];
    char *allmessages;
    MPI_Status *status; /* Info about receive status */
    MPI_Request *req; /* Non-Blocking Requests */
    int my_rank; /* This process ID */
    int num_procs; /* Number of processes in run */
    int source; /* Process ID to receive from */
    int tag = 0; /* Message ID */

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);

    /* clients processes */
    if (my_rank != server_rank) {
        sprintf(message, "Hello world from process# %d", my_rank);
        MPI_Send(message, maximum_message_length + 1, MPI_CHAR, server_rank,
                 tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    } else {
```

No need for non-blocking sends here. Now we go on and receive all these messages on server_rank. We need to loop over all of them and store a request handle for each of them:

```
    /* rank 0 process */
        allmessages = malloc((maximum_message_length+1)*num_procs);
        status = malloc(sizeof(MPI_Status)*num_procs);
        req = malloc(sizeof(MPI_Request)*num_procs);

        for (source = 0; source < num_procs; source++) {
            req[source] = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
            if (source != server_rank) {
                /* Post non-blocking receive for source */
                MPI_Irecv(allmessages+(source*(maximum_message_length+1)),
                          maximum_message_length + 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag,
                          MPI_COMM_WORLD, req+source);
                /* Proceed without waiting on the receive */
                /* (posting further receives */
            }
        }
        /* Wait on all communications to complete */
        MPI_Waitall(num_procs, req, status);
        /* Print the messages in order to the screen */
        for (source = 0; source < num_procs; source++) {
            if (source != server_rank) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",
                        allmessages+(source*(maximum_message_length+1)));
            }
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

After posting the non-blocking receives, we need to wait on all of them to complete, to print the messages in the correct order. To do this, a [MPI_Waitall](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node49.html#Node49) is used, which allows us to block until all request handles are satisfied. Note, that I include the server_rank here for simplicity, but set its request to MPI_REQUEST_NULL initially, so it will be ignored.
If you do not care about the order, you could process the communications as soon as they become available, by looping over the requests and employing MPI_Waitany. That would return as soon as any communication is completed and you could act on the corresponding data.

**With MPI_Gather that code would look like this:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int maximum_message_length = 100;
    const int server_rank = 0;
    char message[maximum_message_length+1];
    char *allmessages;
    int my_rank; /* This process ID */
    int num_procs; /* Number of processes in run */
    int source; /* Process ID to receive from */
    int tag = 0; /* Message ID */

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);

    if (my_rank == server_rank) {
        allmessages = malloc((maximum_message_length+1)*num_procs);
    }
    sprintf(message, "Hello world from process# %d", my_rank);
    MPI_Gather(message, (maximum_message_length+1), MPI_CHAR,
               allmessages, (maximum_message_length+1), MPI_CHAR,
               server_rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (my_rank == server_rank) {
        /* Print the messages in order to the screen */
        for (source = 0; source < num_procs; source++) {
            if (source != server_rank) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",
                        allmessages+(source*(maximum_message_length+1)));
            }
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

And with MPI-3 you can even use a non-blocking [MPI_Igather](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node126.htm).

If you don't care about the ordering, the last part (starting with MPI_Waitall) could be done with MPI_Waitany like this:

```
    for (i = 0; i < num_procs-1; i++) {
        /* Wait on any next communication to complete */
        MPI_Waitany(num_procs, req, &source, status);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",
                allmessages+(source*(maximum_message_length+1)));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much . This is well explained .

Comment: @MikeH. pleased to hear that.